# Scheduling AlarmManager on lastest Android version not working

Tags: java, android, notifications, kotlin, alarmmanager

I've got some problems to schedule an alarm with `AlarmManager` on the latest versions of Android. Due to the idle mode? 
I need to create an alarm to display a recurring notification, but on the latest versions of Android, my alarm is not triggering if the app is killed. 
(Works like a charm on the older API levels)

I've tried `AlarmManager`, Evernote (which use `AlarmManager`) but nothing works.

Does anyone know if there is a way (battery carrying) to schedule an alarm and be sure it'll trigger on the latest Android versions?

Here it's my code to schedule an alarm:

```
public static void schedulePeriodic(long nextReminderTimeInMillis) {
    new JobRequest.Builder(TAG)
            .setExact(nextReminderTimeInMillis)
            .setUpdateCurrent(true)
            .build()
            .schedule();
}
```

Comment: Yes, that what I thought, it's because JobScheduler should not be use for schedule recurring alarms at an exact time, but for background tasks that should be firing when some conditions are reaches ?
But in my case I really need to fire my alarm at an exact time, it's for a reminder notification.

Comment: this https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/GdNrQciPwqo might help

Comment: Thanks for your link Raghunandan, I indeed try `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` which should be what I need, but alarms not triggering on my Huawei mate 10 or OnePlus 5...
I begin to think this could be due to brand's custom battery manager ?

Comment: Could you edit your question and write the exact Android version you couldn't get it working on please.